# How do you modify tensorflow python code so that when you import this into your own python files the modifications are picked up?

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-packaging

I am trying to debug a use-case and the error messages that are given by tensorflow are cryptic. Therefore I want to modify the tensorflow code base to print some values so I see exactly what is going wrong. Unfortunately I am not able to simply modify the python file and run, as the changes are not getting picked up. Is there any extra step to work on? To be concrete

```
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/98a2d7d166c6ba19539e6d1fa57c47c4170ee77b/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py
```

I have modified line 1233

```
 "Your input ran out of data; interrupting training." with "Your input ran out of data; interrupting training. TESTING!!!!"
```

Basically I added some extra log here just to see how this works. However, the changes do not seem to be getting picked up when I run my code which imports tensorflow. I have made the modifications here

```
 /path_to_anaconda/anaconda3/envs/py39tf26cpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Are you sure you are referring to the correct environment when editing data_adapter.py? Could not reproduce your behavior.

Comment: @AloneTogether Oh, are you saying that if you did modify code in the python file the changes are reflected?

Comment: Yes exactly …..